# ML Classification : Encoding categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a beginner at this,

I have a classification problem and my data looks like below:

[image]
and so on...

Result column is dependent variable. None of the data is **Ordinal**. (Name column is having 36 different names.)

As it is categorical data i tried **`OneHotEncoding`** and i got **`ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input`**

Which i understood and referred this : [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521521/testing-text-classification-ml-model-with-new-data-fails) and it got fixed.

Also there was another site : [Medium](https://medium.com/@vaibhavshukla182/how-to-solve-mismatch-in-train-and-test-set-after-categorical-encoding-8320ed03552f) to solve this `ValueError` by using Pandas `factorize` function.

My Question is:

1. what is the correct way to approach this? Should i `factorize` and apply `OneHotEncoding` ?
2. or Since my data is not Ordinal i shouldn't use factorize?
3. I am always getting 100% accuracy. Is it because of the encoding i do ?

**My code below:**

**Training**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("model_data.csv")


dataset['Col1'] = pd.factorize(dataset['Col1'])[0]
dataset['Col2'] = pd.factorize(dataset['Col2'])[0]
dataset['name'] = pd.factorize(dataset['name'])[0]
dataset['ID'] = pd.factorize(dataset['ID'])[0]

X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

# Encoding
# Encoding categorical data
# Encoding the Independent Variable
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ct = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(sparse='False'), [0,1,2,3]),  remainder = 'passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X)


# Encoding the Dependent Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
print(y)

#
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)



from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 5, criterion = 'entropy', max_depth = 5, random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

**Testing**

```
test_data_set =  pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")


test_data_set['Col1'] = pd.factorize(test_data_set['Col1'])[0]
test_data_set['Col2'] = pd.factorize(test_data_set['Col2'])[0]
test_data_set['name'] = pd.factorize(test_data_set['name'])[0]
test_data_set['ID'] = pd.factorize(test_data_set['ID'])[0]

X_test_data = test_data_set.iloc[:, 0:-1].values
y_test_data = test_data_set.iloc[:, -1].values


y_test_data = le.transform(y_test_data)


classifier.fit(X_test_data, y_test_data) #fixes ValueError
y_test_pred = classifier.predict(X_test_data)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test_data, y_test_pred)
print(cm)
print(accuracy_score(y_test_data, y_test_pred))
```

**EDIT**:

- Number of rows in my dataset is 2000.
- The result `accuracy_score` is 1.0

**Confusion Matrix**

```
[[113   0]

 [  0  30]]
```

I am not sure i have around 2000 rows but my TP and TN together has only 143 counts.

Comment: How many rows do you have in yout dataset? Also, dont use fit_transform on your test_data. And also add the results generated in your question.

Comment: @AniketBote I have edited the question. I have removed the fit_transform

Comment: Also, add a confusion matrix. Also, make sure that test data and train data don't contain the same samples. The length of the test data should be at least 20% of the training set and should be representative of all labels.

Comment: Don't you fit your test data with `classifier.fit(X_test_data, y_test_data)` and overwrite your previous training data fit? I think you shouldn't do a `fit` with the test data, just a `predict`

Comment: @Berger Yeah i have also never done it before i just tried it to fix **ValueError**. It maybe wrong.

Comment: @Berger is right if you are calling fit on test data you will get an accuracy of 1.0. Since you are retraining your dataset on that particular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example of how you can use OneHotEncoding for your data to perform binary classification.

You first use one-hot-encoding on all you columns with features, then factorize your Y/N classes in "Result" column to 1/0 view.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("model_data.csv")

dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset , columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'name', 'ID'])
dataset.Result = pd.factorize(dataset.Result)[0]
```

You should get result like it showed below in your resulting dataframe, which you can use for your training/testing steps.

Initial dataframe:

```
  Col1 Col2     name    ID Result
0   AB    A     John -2500      N
1   AB    A     John -2500      N
2    A    A     John -2500      N
3    A    A    Jacob -2500      Y
4    A    A  Micheal -2500      Y
5    A   AB     John -2500      N
6    A    A  Sheldon -2500      Y
7   AB   AB  Sheldon -2500      N
8   AB   AB    Jacob -2500      Y
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
   Result  Col1_A  Col1_AB  Col2_A  Col2_AB  name_Jacob  name_John  name_Micheal  name_Sheldon  ID_-2500
0       0       0        1       1        0           0          1             0             0         1
1       0       0        1       1        0           0          1             0             0         1
2       0       1        0       1        0           0          1             0             0         1
3       1       1        0       1        0           1          0             0             0         1
4       1       1        0       1        0           0          0             1             0         1
5       0       1        0       0        1           0          1             0             0         1
6       1       1        0       1        0           0          0             0             1         1
7       0       0        1       0        1           0          0             0             1         1
8       1       0        1       0        1           1          0             0             0         1
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks! I have trained my model with this and while testing i get **ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.** as my test data has less n_features. How to overcome this ?

Comment: @user3164187, Probably, such question was already answered in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026832/valueerror-number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pd.get_dummies()` method, it's usually pretty reliable. [This guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) should get you started. Cheers!

Comment: My data is Nominal, will the Model consider it as Ordinal if i use get_dummies() ?

Comment: @user3164187 `get_dummies()` is typically meant for nominal data where you'd like to one-hot encode them; if you've got ordinal data, then you'd rather stay away from it, or you could use Quantile-based discretization using `pd.qcut()` and make new columns specifying if your data is within a cut-off range or not. For e.g., if a feature ranges between 0-100, pd.qcut() could make 4 new columns - '0-25', -26-50', '51-75' and '76-100' - with 0s and 1s indicating if that example falls within that range or not.